# .htaccess URL Rewrite domain.de/test with domain.de?user=test

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can i do this? The url domain.de/test should go to domain.de/index.html and give them the attribute user=test.
Ist this possible with .htaccess?
And some other Folder like /image or /fonts should not be rewriten.

Comment: kindly do add your htaccess rule file along with information from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite in your question for better understanding of question.

Comment: Im using html and Javascript in my index.html. When i go to domain.de/test i get "404 not found".

Comment: It would be better to mention URLs like `http://singh.test.com/test123` to `http://singh.test.com/test?user=test123_bla_bla` etc, for better understanding of the question please. Add them in your question not in comments please.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that but this is not the way you should do this. I guess you use PHP so there are libs like https://github.com/bramus/router. NodeJS and Python have this integrated

Comment: Im using html and Javascript in my index.html. When i go to domain.de/test i get "404 not found".

Comment: I think no one ever did that without a backend. I mean you could do that but there is no sense behind that